# invalid registration for fcm in iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

after google launch their new **FCM SDK** with iOS capability i was abel to receive the notification from the console well either the app was in background or in active state now i am trying to make my server send the push notification as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#auth) i follow up the documentation steps as mention in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server but the result is :

> {"multicast_id":XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

**The PHP Script**

```
<?php
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$registrationIds = array('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'

);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
?>
```

this code was found on github https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017 but i make some modification to fit my case

and after searching for related question on stack i just found the following [Notification in iOS using new Firebase Messaging SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541259/notification-in-ios-using-new-firebase-messaging-sdk), and [Invalid Registration Id with my gcm php server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116313/invalid-registration-id-with-my-gcm-php-server) but they could not help me in solving my problem.

> here is the cliend side but as i mentioned before the app receive the notification from the console.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

        if(ver >= 8 && ver<9)
        {
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
            {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

            }
        }else if (ver >=9){

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];


        }
        else{
            //iOS6 and iOS7 specific code
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];

        }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                     name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
        [FIRApp configure];
        [self connectToFcm];




        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return YES;
    }



    - (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
        // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
        // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
        // should be done.
        NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
        NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);
    }




    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {


        NSDictionary *newUserInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"notification"];

        NSLog(@"the user info is : %@",newUserInfo);

        UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

        if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground || state == UIApplicationStateInactive)
        {
            UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.userInfo = newUserInfo;
            localNotification.alertTitle = [newUserInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
            localNotification.alertBody = [newUserInfo objectForKey:@"body"];
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        }



        else if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {


            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1054);
            UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderimage"];
            NSString *title  = [newUserInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
            NSString *body = [newUserInfo objectForKey:@"body"];


            notification = [MPGNotification notificationWithTitle:title subtitle:body backgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:51/255.0 green:51/255.0 blue:51/255.0 alpha:1.0f] iconImage:icon];
            notification.duration = 5.0;
            notification.swipeToDismissEnabled = NO;
            [notification show];
        }
    }

    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
    {
        NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
        token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"content---%@", token);
    }



    - (void)connectToFcm {
        [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: check  `$registrationIds` is in proper format

Comment: did you get the solution for this?

Comment: Yes i get the solution are u having same problem

Comment: I am also having same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: @ZakariaDarwish Please tell me solution for IOS. I also stuck here

Comment: @DesertP have you fixed this issue?

Comment: @ZakariaDarwish how you solved it?

Comment: @Himanth have you solved this?